# What are the salary and perks of Captain America?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-age-of-ultron

Brooklyn is Captain America's home, but times have changed since he was kid 8-9 decades ago. He can't afford a house there, now. This thing really troubled me when he said it in *Avengers: Age of Ultron*. I mean, I really became sympathetic, despite it being intended for fun.

What's the salary Captain America collects from (fallen) S.H.I.E.L.D. and/or Tony's Avengers organization? Can't they gift him a house in Brooklyn? I mean, he is one of Earth's mightiest heroes who help saved the world lots of times.

Comment: Do *any* of the Avengers even get paid for being Avenges?

Comment: @Zibbobz They are Level 5 agents of S.H.I.E.L.D. (source: Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D. TV series). So why not?

Comment: It's quite possible that their salary goes to rebuild the buildings they destroy.

Comment: Tony at least probably doesn't need the paycheck.  And everyone else besides Captain America has a position outside of S.H.I.E.L.D. (Assassin-for-hire, Research Scientist, Millionaire Playboy, Asgardian God, whatever it is Hawkeye does).

Comment: @Zibbobz Captain America can also be rich if he wants to. You know lots of guys always look for handsome mercenaries. Grant Ward and Hunter kind of guys can't even stand a chance in front of him.

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433 Captain America doesn't strike me as the type of guy to become a mercenary.

Comment: @Zibbobz Yeah, that's the problem. But still, he can be actor.

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433 I don't think there's much call for 50s style propaganda shows, and that seems like the only acting training Captain America ever received.

Comment: I think folks in the military are often under-paid, considering the work they do. I bet Cap would actually refuse a free house too.

Comment: @Zibbobz Apparently, Hawkeye is a farmer.

Comment: My guess is that Captain America is the kind of guy who would not take a cent more than he is entitled to by his military rank. Not sure what his rank is.

Comment: Would Earth money (USD since SHIELD is a US organisation) have any meaning or value to Thor?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As a Soldier missing in action, Captain America would be entitled to decades worth of backpay from the moment he was fished out of the ocean. He is easily a multi millionaire.

http://www.daytradingbias.com/?p=135238

Comment: I believe Captain America would bring his Ferrari to compete Tony in the Civil War. Oh, Government processes are slow, so he got the money late.

Answer (score 10):

Truthfully? We don't know.

It seems safe to assume that after the events of *Captain America: The Winter Soldier*, SHIELD are no longer paying Steve Rogers for his services, and by the time *Avengers: Age of Ultron* occurs, Steve is a full-time Avenger, leading a team funded by one of the richest men on the planet, Tony Stark.

However, I don't imagine for a second that any of The Avengers take a paycheck from what they do, for two reasons.

1. It is mentioned in *Avengers: Age of Ultron* that Tony Stark sends in a relief team to areas that have been affected by Avenger activity. This makes it sound as if the Avengers are operating as a (global) public service, one that seeks out threats and dispatches them as they see fit, accountable to no-one but themselves and ensuring that the mess they leave is cleared up too. That implies a lack of government backing (further supported by Tony Stark's claims that "he's just the guy that pays for everything").
2. From a character perspective, the Avengers are clearing up messes that they helped create. I've gone into this area (specifically concerning Thor) more [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/81344/why-is-thor-an-avenger/81350#81350), but it seems safe to say that the rest of the Avengers would follow a similar thought pattern - that they have a responsibility to help, with or without pay.

Add in the fact that the team leader of the Avengers, Steve Rogers, specifically states that he can't afford a property in Brooklyn, and it seems safe to say that members of the Avengers avenge for free.

Comment: In the comics, I believe any Avengers on active duty got a stipend or per diem, as well as being able to stay in the mansion.  So while they are adventuring, they at least have cost of living and minor expenses covered.  Don't know if this applies in the movie-verse.

Comment: @JSM It's never been mentioned. That being said, I got the impression that Bruce Banner at least is living in the Avengers Tower - Stark ask Banner if Cho is OK to set up in HIS lab.

Comment: One of the running jokes in the comics is that Tony Stark pays for basically everything they need, even any building/public property they happen to destroy while out heroing. ("Tony Stark will pay for that!")

Comment: "how fast can we buy this building"?

Comment: Okay fine but altruism is all well and good until you die. Rogers can't help anyone if he's starved to death. He's going to need _some_ money unless he's just completely living off his mates.