# How much do the Avengers (characters) make?

Tags: marvel, avengers

How much do the Avengers get paid, the actual in-universe characters?

A quick Google search for "how much do the avengers make" pulls up Webpages on how much the **actors** make.

Comment: You are saying you think the Avengers get a salary *inside* the MCU?

Comment: Just to clarify, the question is about how much the avengers get paid, in universe, for their consulting or superhero-ing?

Comment: https://comicnewbies.files.wordpress.com/2013/01/avengers-recruitment.jpg

Comment: @Richard Except it seems Spider-man doesn't get a check because he won't reveal his identity. http://comicvine.gamespot.com/avengers/4060-3806/forums/how-do-the-avengers-make-money-650852/?page=1#js-message-6860521

Answer (score 7):

While the actor's earnings make good reading, there also is a bit more info to be found out there.

- Tony Stark/Iron Man: ***undisclosed***
  Tony Stark initially is refused as S.H.I.E.L.D. operative after a review by the Black Widow. He himself would never accept, or indeed need to accept the restrictions of a government position. But he would never say anything about it for tax reasons, of course.
- Natasha Romanoff/Black Widow: ***regular S.H.I.E.L.D. agent salary***
- Steve Rogers/Captain America: ***regular S.H.I.E.L.D. leader salary***
- Clint Barton/Hawkeye: ***regular S.H.I.E.L.D. agent salary***
- Thor Odinson: ***Asgardian liaison***
  Thor's affiliation is firmly Asgardian. So, no earthly salary.
- Bruce Banner/Hulk ***S.H.I.E.L.D. consultant fee***
  S.H.I.E.L.D. brings him in. If they do not pay him it would be abduction. But looks like he has no negotiation leeway at all.

How much then do they get in regular money? This is never disclosed so in the realm of pure speculation. Assessments range from ***59 (US FBI agent entry level) to 120K per year***. These are mainly based on the characteristics of S.H.I.E.L.D. as an agency of the US.

(Some) references:
[What are the salary and perks of Captain America?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/87450/what-are-the-salary-and-perks-of-captain-america)
http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Characters
http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Thor_Odinson_(Earth-199999)
http://historicallyaccuratesteve.tumblr.com/post/93429429217/rainnecassidy-melannen-rgfellows
https://www.quora.com/Do-the-Avengers-get-any-salary
http://lawandthemultiverse.com/2012/11/16/captain-america-and-social-security/
https://www.reddit.com/r/movies/comments/1dy85t/avengers_salary_chart_includes_time_on_screen_too/
https://www.reddit.com/r/shield/comments/382kll/how_much_does_a_shield_agent_get_paid/
https://www.quora.com/Marvel-Comics/What-is-the-salary-of-a-SHIELD-agent
http://www.payscale.com/research/US/Job=FBI_Agent/Salary/3bbf5bd1/Entry-Level

Comment: I can't help thinking the actors names and salaries in this answer confuse it

Comment: @Liath, looks like you are right. I'll update the answer and remove them.

Comment: There is also a fun thing like this: https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/8a/bf/d1/8abfd1f93a647896f1a5d90ac97ca58c.jpg It's not canon but Thor's salary seems pretty legit.

Answer (score 1):

I remember in an old issue of Avengers when Spider Man helped them out and was considered for membership he was thinking how the thousand a week salary would really come in handy.

This was back in the late 80's or early 90's so I am sure by now it has come up. I think it was mentioned that there was a Foundation set up in the name of Tony Starks parents that paid for the Avengers, their mansion, tech and their salaries. The money for the Avengers couldn't be touched by Tony or his company so when he lost his company and went broke the Avengers were still funded.