# Is the Juggernaut immortal by default?

Tags: marvel, x-men, immortality, juggernaut

Originally, I was going to ask "How old is Cain Marco as the Juggernaut?"

Then I got to thinking... *technically* speaking, Cain was always seen as Charles *older* half/step brother (depending on the version). However, Charles is *routinely* seen as *more aged* than Marco, who, without his helmet, is seen to be a man in his early 40s, at his oldest, and *usually* late 20s to early 30s.

It then occurred to me, that that *would* likely be the age at which Marco first touched the gem of Cytorakk, and thus was probably "frozen" at that age.

We already know that as an avatar of Cytorakk, Cain needs no food, sleep or even oxygen to survive, making him functionally unkillable. Logically, that would mean he creates no waste chemicals either, and would then not be subject to other metabolic processes. But then, I must ask...

**Is he also literally Immortal, as in ageless, and invulnerable to time or entropy?**

Cytorakk *himself* (the other dimensional entity from which the Juggernaut's magic originated) is timeless, that we know...

But are there any canon comics that literally give his avatar, Cain Marco, part or a human version of that immortality?

While we're on it, if someone wishes to take an educated guess at Marco's age, as well, that would be appreciated.

**Note:** Because they are not based in the same laws, *NO film version of the Juggernaut is applicable here.* Comic book and cartoon versions only.

Comment: [Related, possible dupe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14682/avengers-and-x-men-how-many-of-them-are-immortals)

Comment: @Ben Similar, but not really a dupe. A question asking about Spiderman's strength and one asking if his strength is the result of the _spider DNA_ or if its more an aspect of the _Radiation_ are related, yes...but not duplicated. This question is asking **specifically** if Juggernaut's powers include immortality, and if there is _any_ canon information that can confirm this data on _this_ character, not in the same general way related to most Avengers and X-Men.

Comment: Could be a tricky question as Juggernaut has been powered-up, de-powered and semi-powered at different times. I've got a feeling in the back of my mind that the extent of his powers are also related to the extent of Cytorakks at any given time, which can be affected by external forces.

Comment: @KMo External forces, you say? The only time I've ever seen that is when someone else has the gem. What other external factors do you mean? Can you give an example?