# Can the Incredible Hulk die?

Tags: marvel, the-incredible-hulk

In [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14243/is-thor-the-only-avenger-that-cant-die/14281#14281) some users pointed out that the Hulk cannot age or ages really slow in relationship with normal people, which makes him an immortal.

But my question is this: Can he die in a battle?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The simple answer is yes, but it varies how it is possible.

In the one-shot comic "[Hulk: The End](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hulk:_The_End)" written by Peter David, Hulk is almost invincible. He survives a nuclear holocaust when no one else does. Although, Bruce Banner is not invincible. He dies and hulk realizes he cannot transform without dying also. From the synopsis:

> Suffering a painful heart attack, Banner realizes how much his punishment resembles that of Prometheus, the Last Titan; condemned to stay forever alive even while animals devour him, speculating that the Hulk's suffering is Earth punishing him for humanity's sins as the embodiment of the nuclear wars that destroyed Earth. As he dies, the Hulk's persona arises in his mind. [...]
>
> The next morning, the Hulk somberly sits outside the cave, musing in his inner monologue: "Banner is gone...got rid of him last night." As he remembers the confrontation, he realizes that **if he were ever to change back to Banner, he would die also**.

In the Lou Ferrigno version of Hulk, there was a TV movie called [*The Death of the Incredible Hulk*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Death_of_the_Incredible_Hulk). Hulk falls from a exploding plane and dies on the ground. Although in true comic style, "there was talk of another Incredible Hulk television movie which would resurrect the character." Unfortunately, Bill Bixby (who portrayed Bruce Banner) dies before that ever happened.

In the comics [Tales to Astonish #90 & 91](http://www.supermegamonkey.net/chronocomic/entries/tales_to_astonish_9091.shtml), the Abomination is created and kills Hulk. He is revived shortly after though.
[image: Abomination kills Hulk]

In the [Old Man Logan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Man_Logan) comic series, Hulk kills and eats Logan. "Logan recuperates within Banner's stomach and bursts out, killing him." See below:
[image: Logan Kills Hulk]

In [Thor #73](http://comicstore.marvel.com/Thor-73/digital-comic/7234) (The Reigning Part 5), Thor kills the Hulk and others. Although, I believe at the end of The Reigning story arc Thor turns back time. [This gallery](http://www.comicartfans.com/GalleryPiece.asp?Piece=275570) has several pages from that issue, such as the one below. Thor also snapped Hulk's neck in a What If? issue that I couldn't find.
[image: Thor 73: Hulk Dies]

Other characters have supposedly killed the Hulk, such as Deadpool, Red Hulk (Rulk) and Galactus. But they were all in "what if?" type comics, and I couldn't find solid details online. I found evidence that Hulk killed Red Hulk (not the opposite), but this stands to reason if one hulk can die, the Hulk could die.
[image: Red Hulk dies]

More recently, Hulk was killed by Hank Pym in [What If...? Season 1, Episode 3](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt13106188) by entering his body with his Ant-Man suit and increasing Hulk's cells using pym particles until he exploded.
[image: Hulk growing in size]

Answer (score 11):

In *The Avengers*, Banner said that he had tried to kill himself, but it didn't work.

> In case you needed to kill me, but you can't! I know! I tried!... I got low. I didn't see an end, so I put a bullet in my mouth... and the other guy spit it out! So I moved on. I focused on helping other people. I was good, until you dragged me back into this freak show and put everyone here at risk! [*Bruce Banner* in *The Avengers*]

There are many theories on how you could possibly kill him, such as [ripping out his heart or decapitation](http://www.killermovies.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-338936-how-to-kill-the-hulk.html), or he could be killed by another super being like in a few of the comics. Other than that, though, I have found no evidence that Bruce Banner/The Hulk can die.

Comment: I'm sure he could not survive being launched into the sun or going through a black hole.

Comment: @Jason: You should look at Nullbreaker's answer, Hulk survived a black hole.

Comment: @DrakeSAN I hear you on the Lore comic evidence but sometimes don't you want to say "Hey, that Lore is just dumb."? That "black hole" looks ridiculous like a tornado. A modern sci-fi comic would not depict a black hole like that as nearing a black hole results in an exponential gravitational difference between atoms which turns everything into string cheese, even Hulk, as he's made of atoms too, Lore aside. I just blasphemed but in this case, I have to.

Comment: Depending on how is written. The Hulk has a regeneration rate even greater than Logan. He should be able to regenerate from a single cell.

Answer (score 8):

He can die but he's awfully difficult to kill. Brute strength doesn't work, at least it hasn't for many, many years. Certain forms of magic can kill him. During World War Hulk someone used a wishing machine to kill hill but he was immediately brought back to life. Zeus turned off his healing factor and his ability to get stronger and nearly beat him to death. Red Hulk removed his gamma energy and reverted him to Banner. That also happed in Infinity 6 though the effects were temporary and I was under the impression Banner wasn't attacked because he would revert back to Hulk.

Hulk survivng a black hole :

[image: Hulk Black Hole Feat Defenders 003 001]

[image: Hulk Black Hole Feat Defenders 003 002]

[image: Hulk Black Hole Feat Defenders 003 003]

[image: Hulk Black Hole Feat Defenders 003 004]

[image: Hulk Black Hole Feat Defenders 003 005]

Also nuclear explosions are said to be hotter than the sun and Gladiators heat vision is said to be hotter than the core of a star, Hulk has survived both.

Answer (score 0):

I have only seen the *Avengers Assemble* film but based on that it seems like he is pretty much unkillable.  He was able to take a dozen ships concentrating fire on him specifically without seeming to be injured.  He grunted with effort and frustration as he was being overwhelmed but did not seem to show any pain.

Banner was not able to kill himself buy shooting himself in the mouth, the Hulk just spat the bullet out.

However, this does not mean he is invincible.  He could, for example, be thrown into space which would render him useless although alive.  Perhaps he could be frozen etc?  It is not clarified whether Banner could be injured (say blinded) which might render the Hulk less effective.

He can be stopped by a resourceful opponent but in terms of brute force he is a serious presence.

Comment: Could the divebomber give any hints on how the answer could be improved?

Answer (score 0):

The Hulk can but can't die. In a certain comic Hulk (Bruce Banner) kills Red Hulk (or Rulk). It proves that he can die but only by someone of equal invincibility such as Hulk vs. Rulk. By Avengers' logic he is invincible because Banner shot himself in the mouth and I quote "the other guy spit it out," so unless a godly or equally invincible force is acted upon the Hulk, he is unkillable.

Comment: Hello and welcome to the Stack Exchange. Quick note: "The Hulk can but can't die" is not a good start to an answer. Plus you are mixing canons by referencing the comics and the MCU (which **do** differ). I'd suggest checking out the [Tour](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand how to better ask and answer questions here. It's not a typical conversational forum. Please don't be discouraged, we were all new here at some point.

Comment: Having said that, keep in mind a more detailed answer was already accepted. (Note the green check-mark above for Matt's answer from Dec 13, 2013 at 18:02.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes he can, but he is almost invincible to anything. Bruce Banner doesn't want to be the Hulk and he can't change it, when he gets mad he transforms. Basically, the Hulk is almost impossible to beat and some say he's immortal but I do believe that Bruce Banner ages when he's not the Hulk so Bruce Banner is not immortal so it's kind of like a Dr. Jeykll and Mr. Hyde.

Answer (score 0):

I have been reading into this all night after reading the *World War Hulk* series and wondering if he could die. It was said by one of the super beings that Hulk, even if disintegrated, would reform due to the intense healing. So beheading is out.

The best solution to the Hulk would be someone with the Phoenix powers, preferably Rachel Summers who commanded the power at it's strongest, to simply disintegrate him, absorb his life force and then cast the particles to every end of the universe. That would be the end of Hulk for a very very long time.

Answer (score 0):

A gamma or nuclear bomb, can kill him if he is right in the place of explosion, that is how Hulk killed the Maestro, who is way more powerful than him. I think the key is in the overpowered abilities, there is a point where too much power is concentrated and a body, even hulk's can not retain it.

Comment: Can you add some references?

Comment: J.Ryder that is no longer the case. During Aaron's run Hulk stood in the heart of a gamma bomb and only lost his hair and eyebrows (Incredible Hulk 6 & 7, 2012). During the Agent of Time arc (Indestructible Hulk 15), Hulk took the same gamma bomb that created him and became the Uberhulk - an incarnation that starts with double the base power of a normal Hulk. During the Marvel Knights arc (issue 4) Banner Hulks up after getting caught in a gigantic gamma bomb then minutes later takes another gamma bomb then reverts back into Banner although at this point his enemy has died so maybe that is why

Comment: Not really. The Hulk has survive Nuclear explosions. You need something more destructive. A trip to the sun might do the trick nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Thanos beat him in the infinaty gauntlet but thanos had the infinaty gems and was deemed a god, hence him beating most of the marvel universe up at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Will edit to add the page, but in Punisher kill the Marvel universe, the Punisher does kill Hulk, with a arrow in the eye.

However, it does not count as it is a "What if" where almost all this alternate universe is affected by a zombie virus.

Comment: The Punisher Kills the Marvel Universe is an out of universe "What If?" type tale and therefore doesn't count.

Comment: @Monty129: I ll edit to make it more clear : )

Answer (score -4):

Listen guys It really is just impossible to kill the Hulk. No matter what happens whether he gets hit by a gamma bomb or cast to all the ends of the universe one way or another he will still return as the Incredible Hulk.

Comment: Welcome to scifi.stackexchange! Matt's answer provides some canonical evidence that Hulk _can_ die. Do you have any sources, that Matt is wrong and Hulk didn't died then? Btw: Sources are always most welcome around here!

Answer (score -4):

LOL. I know how the Hulk can die, from my opinion hulk can die easily when he was in human form. Trust me, you will think that what Bruce Banner said in Avenger is true ( that he can't die):

> "I put a bullet in my mouth, and the other guy spit it out"

From what I can think of, Bruce Banner still can die, but in a crazy way. What if Bruce Banner in human form exploded his head with a grenade or even with c4? Or he chopped his head off with a katana? I'm pretty sure that these incidences would end with the Hulk's death.

Comment: Do you have any evidence to support this? Purely speculative answers aren't generally accepted on this site.

Comment: Yes please provide your factual evidence references for these fictional fantasy characters.