# Could HYDRA have killed Bruce Banner?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-incredible-hulk, captain-america-the-winter-soldier

In *Captain America: The Winter Soldier*, HYDRA had a plan that seemed good on paper, but I wondered **how would they deal with the Hulk?**

We know from *Avengers* that conventional guns (e.g., his suicide attempt) or the alien weapons used by the Chitauri couldn’t kill him. Did SHIELD or HYDRA have some specialised weaponry to neutralise or kill the Hulk?

If they couldn’t kill him, did they have some other plan to contain him?

Comment: They referenced Banner as being a threat picked up by their algorithm. That isn't *necessarily* the same as saying that the ships would have fired upon him.

Comment: @phantom42 ahh I see as I said I've only seen it once, I thought they had said any threat would be taken out but I see now

Comment: As-is, this question may be a dupe of [Can the Incredible Hulk die?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/46243/can-the-incredible-hulk-die). I might recommend editing to focus more on SHIELD/HYDRA's capabilities of accomplishing this.

Comment: @alexwlchan Thanks for the edit! Thats exactly what I wanted to ask

Comment: “They referenced Banner as being a threat picked up by their algorithm. That isn't necessarily the same as saying that the ships would have fired upon him.” For all we know, their algorithm picked up Banner *before* the accident that turned him into the Hulk.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is at least one solution I can think of while sticking to the cinematic universe canon.

Based on Agents of SHIELD, SHIELD and therefore HYDRA has access to space travel and rockets. Even assuming he can not be killed, if HYDRA is able to launch him into space, probably via trickery or some kind of temporary restraint, he would be sufficiently neutralized. (I doubt it would be too hard to convince a scientist to go into space, and if they were still under the guise of SHIELD they could just claim it was some kind of mission) No matter how strong or indestructible you are you can't do much if floating in a vacuum. Obviously this may or may not have been HYDRA's plan but they had access to the necessary resources.

Apparently the "send into space" solution has been used during at least one comic arc, "Planet Hulk"

Comment: Is that not just the solution that Tony Stark, Reed Richards and the other members of the Illuminati came up with at the beginning of Planet Hulk?

Comment: @AllyMorgan: just what I was thinking: [that plan might not end well](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_War_Hulk).

Comment: @AllyMorgan I didn't know that, I don't read the comics. But if it was used in the comics then I think we can conclude that Marvel considers it a valid solution as well.

Anyway, the only reason that plan didn't work (according to what i'm reading) is because the plot demanded that he conveniently run into a wormhole that got him to a populated planet instead of floating around in the middle of nowhere.

Comment: @Lawton In the comics, it was a valid *idea* that seemed good at the time. It ended *horribly* for everyone involved.

Comment: @lawton Thank you for the great answer!

Comment: Here's another incident, where a cosmic powered Spider-Man punched the Hulk into orbit. This was at a point where he would turn into Banner at dawn, at which point he could die. http://static.comicvine.com/uploads/original/11111/111117347/3584834-6949405134-23999.jpg