# Has Wolverine ever beaten The Hulk in a fight?

Tags: marvel, wolverine, the-incredible-hulk

Wolverine and Hulk are two Marvel characters that have incredible powers of healing/recovery, making them extremely difficult (potentially impossible) to kill. In addition, both of them have super-human levels of strength and power (Hulk because of his anger-based strength, Wolverine because of his adamantium-enhanced bones.)

Have these two characters ever faced off against one another? In particular, has there ever been a situation where Wolverine was able to defeat The Hulk (kill, subdue, or otherwise incapacitate him)?

Comment: I've created a [meta question](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6867/inconsistency-in-shark-vs-gorilla-closing) because I don't think close votes are being dealt out consistently with these kinds of questions.

Comment: @AlfredoHernández - the OP wants to know specific instances of hulk vs wolverine clashes.. On the other hand your question gives answers to "100 ways to kill hulk" :)

Comment: @RicoRicochet you are right. My fault.

Comment: You might be interested in the film *Hulk vs. Wolverine* from 2009

Answer (score 32):

Well as per [Marvel's Ultimate Wolverine vs Hulk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultimate_Wolverine_vs._Hulk) comic book series, when Wolverine is hired to kill Hulk (who is in Tibet), Hulk tears Wolverine in half (thats right). He throws the legs **4 miles up the mountain**.

[image: Hulk Angry]

Even with this amount of huge physical damage Wolverine is still alive and using his keen senses finds his missing body parts. He does so by sniffing it out (handy power I must say).

[image: Sniffing Power]

Well then he does a 4 mile climb uphill with his claws,

[image: Long way to climb to stand on them feet]

This series also shows the arrival of She-Hulk with famous dialogue by Hulk -  **"Betty break Hulk's heart... now Hulk break Betty!"**

There are other numerous examples in Marvel universe where Hulk has faced off with Wolverine, most of the time wolverine has backed off from fight after being reminded the trauma faced at the hands of Hulk. **"Hulk knows you. Hulk tore you in half!"**

This answer is based on Marvel Ultimate universe Earth 1610. I do not have knowledge of all of the universes, maybe in some other universe as pointed out by Paul, the scenario may be different (i.e. Hulk gets sliced to size).

---

*special thanks to Wad Cheber & Daft*

Comment: I thought Betty was the Red She-Hulk; the She-Hulk is Jennifer Walters?

Comment: Add the [image...](http://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--c6M2IiZo--/c_fit,fl_progressive,q_80,w_636/17j9qqitkp0mkjpg.jpg)

Comment: anyway the credit goes to you.. it is really good to see such variety of stories in so many universes..

Comment: This is the best picture that has ever appeared in a comic book.

Comment: @Michael Edenfield-Sharp eye, Michael. Yes, the original She-Hulk is Jennifer Walters. However, this is Ultimate She-Hulk, a whole different kind of character, which is quite common in the Ultimate Marvel Universe. Other examples include Giant-Man using a sports-like spandex for his growth suit, a black Nick Fury, and a Captain America who is now truly 'the man out of time', as this series debuted in the early 2000s.

Comment: @RicoRicochet - if you had included the quote about Hulk having thrown Wolverine's legs 6 miles up the Himalayan mountains, I might have given you a bounty.

Comment: @WadCheber - mission accepted, just for the fun of it. :D

Comment: @RicoRicochet - I can help you out (by the way, it was 4 miles, not 6)  [Page 1](http://i.imgur.com/wpUAkfY.jpg) [Page 2](https://dcomixologyssl.sslcs.cdngc.net/i/2386/6239/4d1aa2f2b01f7.jpg?h=d057ff851973530066795d3179ec6367)

Comment: It is worth a bounty of 100 points, I'd say.

Comment: @RicoRicochet - thanks!  That is the only Hulk or Wolverine comic I've ever read, because how could I not read something with that picture (Hulk holding half of Wolverine in each hand) in it?  I can award the bounty in 23 hours.

Comment: This comics was "animated" into the most awesome mini-series. And "animated" here means we essentially get shown the panels [without dialog] whilst voice actors speak [the dialog].

Comment: For me the best part is - "..well they aint gonna grow themselves back.."

Comment: +1. Seems like any answer to a question asking whether they have ever fought should note that Wolverine's first appearance was as Hulk's adversary.

Answer (score 27):

In *[Old Man Logan](http://marvel.wikia.com/Old_Man_Logan)* (which is kind of a *What-If?* story, although — thanks @phantom42! — is set on [Earth-807128](http://marvel.wikia.com/Earth-807128)), Wolverine

> is eaten by the Hulk, but heals inside his digestive system and cuts his way out, killing the Hulk in the process. [It’s... not pleasant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWAkw.jpg).

So if we take that as canon, yup, Wolverine can beat the Hulk.

Comment: Old Man Logan is set in [Earth-807128](http://marvel.wikia.com/Earth-807128).

Comment: wow.. irrespective of the background universe, what a finding.. +1 from me..

Comment: @phantom42: thank you! And we will apparently be revisiting it during this year’s *Secret War*.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - get a bigger version of your picture, I think it would be more entertaining :) lets go head on for this bounty :) you from a hulk-salad view, & mine from a wolverine-kebab view :)

Comment: you can get a bigger picture of gutted hulk in this http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/46243/can-the-incredible-hulk-die?rq=1

Comment: @RicoRicochet: excellent, who *doesn’t* want a bigger picture of a guy cutting his way out of a monster’s stomach?! I think the bounty should be all yours, but cheers for the image tip, mine was oddly tiny.

Answer (score 11):

In one of the What If? (# 31) storylines, an altered version of the famous Wolverine/Hulk battle from The Incredible Hulk # 181 is shown.

[image: Cover-Art]

The difference? In this altered fight, Wolverine goes into a berserker rage, slashing the Hulk in a blind, crazed fury until the ol' Jade Giant (Stan Lee's nickname for The Hulk) falls dead in front of him.

[image: Hulk-Green-Salad]

As the people of Earth begin a manhunt for Wolverine, he is approached by Magneto and The Brotherhood of Evil Mutants (Mastermind, Blob, & Lorelei) to aid in fighting mankind. Magneto then sends Wolverine to the X-Mansion, where, surprise, he falls in love with Jean Grey. So needless to say, when Magneto and the Brotherhood attempt to kill Jean and the X-Men, Logan waits until Magneto's back is turned and manages to sneak up on him, impaling him. As Magneto lays dying he uses his powers to force Wolverine to kill himself with his own claws.

So, if you're reading the What If? version of things, yes, Wolverine CAN indeed kill the Hulk (even if it does cause the death of him and Magneto as well).

Comment: The "What If?" books are completely non-canon and shouldn't be used as a true measure of anyone's abilities. Further, what does Wolverine killing Magneto have anything to do with anything?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite, ah well, after your edit, this answer is much better, so m adding a few images..

Comment: @RicoRicochet: paragraphs man, they’re our friend. Images even more so, grand stuff.

Answer (score 3):

Beaten, no. Their first encounter, Hulk 181, ended in a stale-mate and in their most recent encounter, Hulk 12 (Volume 3), Hulk defeats both Thing & Wolverine. Hulk also has regenerative healing powers, the madder he gets, the stronger AND more durable he becomes. Wolverine can be killed by drowning, he is not as invincible as many believe. Hulk? He grows gills underwater.

Answer (score 1):

In the mini-series *Savage Wolverine* (2013), there is a Hulk confrontation in the Savage Land.  As the following excerpt pages show, the Hulk goes down for a full "ten count".  (The (spoilers?) Hulk's regeneration power has him recover before the series ends, so don't be too alarmed)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In **The Punisher: Confederacy of Dunces** (Ennis), Wolverine, Spider-Man, and Daredevil team up to bring Frank to justice.  Frank unleashes the Hulk on them (...it's a long story), and the Hulk punches Wolverine so hard he lands in Boston.

From New York.

In order to get back, Logan has to take a train.

Comment: This is answering the opposite question though. The question is whether or not, through all the years and fights, if Wolverine has ever won. Answering that the Hulk beat Wolverine in one instance doesn't answer the question very well.

Comment: And the current top-voted answer with a hundred rep bounty says the exact same thing.  I was answering the first of the OP's two questions, which was "Has Wolverine ever fought the Hulk?"