# When did the Hulk fall into a black hole?

Tags: story-identification, marvel, the-incredible-hulk, black-hole

I have read a lot of questions and answers about the Hulk here, and several people seem to casually mention him falling in a black hole (and surviving, because who needs physics).

The thing is, it's never the main point of the answer, so everyone overlooks that part and I've never seen anyone question it. On the other hand, I could never find when that happened (issue, year, anything?). I couldn't even confirm it happened.

So, did the Hulk (or any of the other hulk-like characters, like she-hulk) ever fall in a black hole, and if so, when?

Comment: You might want to look at @Nullbreaker’s answer here: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/48018/3567

Answer (score 3):

The instance you refer to, [mentioned in this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/48018/5184), occurred in [Defenders #3, published in 1972](http://www.comicvine.com/the-defenders-3-four-against-the-gods/4000-12735/).

You'll note that it's never actually referred to as "a black hole", just a "hole in the very fabric of this macrocosm" and "a maelstrom".

[Comicvine describes](http://www.comicvine.com/the-defenders-3-four-against-the-gods/4000-12735/):

> Dr. Strange accidentally transports himself and his compatriots from the Valley of the Undying Ones to the Realm Of the Nameless One, this is after a failed attempt to help the Silver Surfer escape Earth and return to his home planet. There, in the realm, they find and rescue Barbara Norriss, previously sacrificing herself to save Strange. The group is caught in a violent maelstrom which sucks them towards a hole in the macrocosm.

[image: cover image]