# In which comic book Bruce Banner/Hulk is shown as the last survivor on earth?

Tags: marvel, comics, episode-identification, the-incredible-hulk

I've heard it is considered as a very depressing comic book story, as the Hulk remains the last survivor on earth, after some kind of nuclear war wipes out the entire human race.

Which comic book is this ?

Comment: Dude, you literally only needed to Google `hulk last ` and then it even autocompletes

Comment: Also answered [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/14279/70236)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Thor the only Avenger that can't die?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14243/is-thor-the-only-avenger-that-cant-die)

Answer (score 2):

[***Hulk: The End***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hulk:_The_End)

[image: cover image]

Written by Peter David, it is a part of [*The End*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_End_(comics)) series.

This is a one-shot comic in which the whole population of the Earth dies in nuclear Holocaust. Naturally, Hulk can survive this, but he's left completely alone.

Comment: Looks like Hulk goes on to become a super mutant in the post-apocalypse Fallout world.

Comment: Starting to look like Swamp Thing.